# Printing a function several times

Tags: python, function, return

I'm new to python and am getting stuck printing the function that will print:

> "99 bottles of beer on the wall 99 bottles of beer
>   Take one down and pass it around, 98 bottles of beer on the wall 
>   98 bottles of beer on the wall 98 bottles of beer
>   Take one down and pass it around, 97 bottles of beer on the wall
>   97 bottles of beer on the wall 97 bottles of beer
>   Take one down and pass it around, 96 bottles of beer on the wall"

This is my code:

```
def sing(number):
    number = 99
    print(number, "bottles of beer on the wall", number, "bottles of beer")
    print("Take one down and pass it around, ", end='')
    number -= 1
    print(number, "bottles of beer on the wall")
    return number

print(sing(sing(sing(number))))
```

Can someone help me out where I'm going wrong? Would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: You've got to learn how to use `for` loops.

Comment: You need a loop (for, while, etc) take your pick.

Comment: Downvoting this is harsh. This is definitely not the worst question I've seen. OP at least provided code and an expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code as you've written it is that you're redefining `number` every time you call the function, rather than using the value that you've passed in. You can fix it just by removing the first line of your function, and you can drop your final `print`

```
def sing(number):
    print(number, "bottles of beer on the wall", number, "bottles of beer")
    print("Take one down and pass it around, ", end='')
    number -= 1
    print(number, "bottles of beer on the wall")
    return number

sing(sing(sing(99)))
```

Comment: Ah so simple! The pain of learning...this works perfectly. It's exactly what I was looking for -Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a loop? You can use `range` to step `number` back down from `99` to `1`.

```
def sing(number):
    print(number, "bottles of beer on the wall", number, "bottles of beer")
    print("Take one down and pass it around, ", end='')
    print(number-1, "bottles of beer on the wall")

for number in range(99, 0, -1):
    sing(number)
```

Otherwise you can add a loop in the function itself

```
def sing(number):
    while number > 1:
        print(number, "bottles of beer on the wall", number, "bottles of beer")
        print("Take one down and pass it around, ", end='')
        number -= 1
        print(number, "bottles of beer on the wall")

sing(99)
```